# Impossible to set A2DP profile on bluetooth headset on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I know this was asked a lot of times, but honestly I've tried everything that I could find over the internet and still couldn't resolve this.

I am a beginner user of Ubuntu 20.04 and I am having issues setting A2DP profile for a pair of bluetooth headset, and the quality is very bad.

- I have paired, trusted and connected the headphones via terminal `bluetoothctl` then `pair`, `trust`, `connect`, didn't work
- also installed `Blueman` and did the same process there again with no luck

After this I've tried to:

- set the profile A2DP firstly from OS GUI that didn't work
- then I've tried from `Blueman` but no success here either -> `(Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink)`
- installed `pavucontrol` and tried again from there - in `pavucontrol` I go to Config tab and in headphone's profile dropdown I can see `High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)(unavailable)` so of course, I cannot set it here also

I have also checked `pacmd list-cards`, checked the `index` of headphones, then `pacmd set-card-profile <index> a2dp_sink` but I get `Failed to set card profile to 'a2dp_sink'.`. I've also tried to `sudo pacmd set-card-profile <index> a2dp_sink` and now I get `No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.` PulseAudio is installed, I've checked with `pulseaudio --version` `pulseaudio 13.99.1`.

I've edited the `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file and added this line in the end of it: `Disable=Headset`, this didn't work. I've also tried to add same line in `main.conf` - no success.

With `bluez` installed, I've also enabled this line `Name = BlueZ` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, again nothing.

In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` I've also uncommented `#MultiProfile = off` and changed it to `MultiProfile = multiple`, nothing happened.

So after mixing all the steps above and restarted bluetooth and re paired headphone a million times, I gave up and I'm writing for help.

Please give any hint on what could be the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried doing the following?

"If PulseAudio fails when changing the profile to A2DP with bluez 4.1+ and PulseAudio 3.0+, you can try disabling the Socket interface from `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` by removing the line `Enable=Socket` and adding line `Disable=Socket`." And then restart using `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

Source: [Archwiki bluetooth Headset Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth_headset#A2DP_not_working_with_PulseAudio)

This solution worked for me on Pop! OS 20.04 LTS.

Edit: I faced the same issue again, and removing `Disable=Socket` line from the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` makes it work again. Will update with any more changes...but I am not sure how world works anymore.

Comment: I did, but it did not help

Comment: 'systemctl' not sytemctl, using just sudo systemctl restart bluetooth worked for me

Comment: Worx on `ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`. Just Added `Disable=Socket` to the end of `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` (it wasn't defined at all), restarted bluetooth. Cheers

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 23.10 too - as on 23 March 2024. Here is my /etc/bluetooth/main.conf :- 

[General]
Disable=Socket

[Policy]
AutoEnable=true

Answer (score 2):

I too tried so many things but after a restart, I just did "killall pulseaudio", my system automatically reconnected with my headphone and problem is gone

Comment: Just tried this and it helped.

Comment: ` killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio: no process found
`
As I switchted to pipewire. Problem persists

Answer (score 2):

I had faced with this issue after buying the new headphones. After digging I had realized that the issue was caused by `alsa-bluez-utils` package and running `alsa` process. After removing this unnecessary package all works fine.

So, if you've faced with this issue, check output of `ps aux | grep blu`.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, what I found was when selecting headset's mic output, ubuntu does not allow to use a2dp.
[image: a2dp selected]

[image: Headset with mic selected]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 I tried literally everything and nothing worked. 
 One day it randomly got fixed without me doing absolutely nothing, the next day as soon as I started my PC the problem was there again.
 
I haven't really *solved* it, but now I'm able to switch from a2dp sink to hfp and viceversa with no problem. 
 ***What I do is:*** start the PC, put on the headset and connect it, (check if by chance it's already working correctly - but it never is), remove it and let it go in standby *(I wait ~1 hour simply leaving it on the desk)*, then put it back on and, as soon as it automatically says "Connected" again, a2dp works.
 I also noticed that when the a2dp issue is there, I cannot use the touch commands on the headset, but after the waiting I do.
 
 Not sure if this can help, but you might as well give it a chance.